# MS Access 2010 - find unmatched wizard on more than one field

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two tables in Microsoft Access 2010, and I would like to find the unmatched rows between them based on two fields instead of one. Ideally, I would like to be able to do this using the 'Find unmatched Query Wizard', but at the moment I cannot find a way to do that.

Is there any way of being able to find the unmatched rows based on two fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "unmatched" wizard only supports matches based on one field.

You can start with a single field and then edit the query (in SQL View) to include a second field in the join condition.

For example, pretend the wizard gives you this for matching based on `Field1` ...

```sql
FROM
    TableA LEFT JOIN TableB
    ON TableA.Field1 = TableB.Field1
WHERE (((TableB.Field1) Is Null));
```

But you also want `Field2` considered for the match.  Simply add that field to the `ON` clause ...

```sql
ON TableA.Field1 = TableB.Field1 AND TableA.Field2 = TableB.Field2
```

Comment: Thank you! This achieves my aim as well!

Answer (score 1):

1. Start with a normal query, joining both tables (on both fields)
2. Switch to SQL view, change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`
3. Back in Design view, add a criterium `Is Null` on a field of the second table.