# How do I compare records of 2 access tables on multiple fields with concatenation rather than checking for Null fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am comparing two tables and trying to get returned the differences between them.
The [ID] field however should be ignored.
I have tried the following but that did not return any results.

[image]

```
SELECT [x].[NBR] & [x].[TXT] AS [KEY], x.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM A)  AS x LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM B)  AS y ON (x.[NBR] = y.[NBR]) 
AND (x.[TXT] = y.[TXT])
WHERE (([x].[NBR] & [x].[TXT])<>([y].[NBR] & [y].[TXT]))
```

The desired outcome of above example would be:

| ID | NBR | TXT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 412 | 402 | Skyler |

or

| ID | NBR | TXT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 800 | 402 | Skyler |

or

| NBR | TXT |
| --- | --- |
| 402 | Skyler |

I am using concatenation of fields rather than checking for Null fields because I am applying this on much bigger tables called from VB which results sometimes in a `SQL Too complex` error while the above does not.

It works on tables for which I am comparing all fields, but cannot get it to work when omitting a fields as in the example above.

Comment: please always include the sql as text  as well as a screenshot - make it easier for the people helping you

Comment: Wouldn't ID 800 return with NBR 401? Did you try using the Access Find Unmatched query wizard? Need to check if a field is Null not if fields are not equal. Review https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ms_access/ms_access_unmatched_query_wizard.htm

Comment: Checking if field is Null works in most cases, but my example is just a simple representation of what I am actually doing. Sometimes I need to apply it so very big tables by means of VB and will then run into an error "SQL Too complex".  The above meets my needs when comparing all fields, but cannot get it to work for comparing some fields

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS Access 2010 - find unmatched wizard on more than one field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046621/ms-access-2010-find-unmatched-wizard-on-more-than-one-field)

Comment: @June7 Unfortunately it does not. I am looking for a solution close to the one I provided because of reasons I mentioned in my post (see update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery to find the matches, then rule these out with a Left Join:

```sql
SELECT 
    A.ID, 
    A.NBR, 
    A.TXT 
FROM 
    A 
LEFT JOIN 

    (SELECT A.ID
    FROM A 
    INNER JOIN B 
    ON (A.TXT = B.TXT) AND (A.NBR = B.NBR)) AS AB

    ON A.ID = AB.ID
WHERE 
    AB.ID Is Null
```

Output:

```
ID  NBR TXT
412 402 Skyler
```